# Stack abstract data type in C

Tags: c, stack, abstract-data-type

Can you please tell me what I did wrong? I'm getting SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) error. Is single linked list the best way to implement a stack abstract data type? I'm trying not to use global variables so that's why I used double pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack{
    int data;
    struct stack *next;
}STACK;

void push(STACK **head,STACK **tail,int n)
{
    STACK *x;
    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        (*head)=malloc(sizeof(STACK));
        (*head)->data=n;
        (*head)->next=NULL;
        *tail=*head;
    }
    else
    {
        x=malloc(sizeof(STACK));
        x->data=n;
        x->next=NULL;
        (*head)->next=x;
        (*head)=(*head)->next;
    }
}

void show(STACK *tail)
{
    if(tail!=NULL)
    {
        printf("From tail to head:\n");
        while(tail!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\n",tail->data);
            tail=tail->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The stack is empty!\n");
    }
}

void pop(STACK **head,STACK *tail)
{
    STACK *x;
    if(*head!=tail)
    {
        x=*head;
        while(tail->next->next!=NULL)
            tail=tail->next;
        printf("pop: %d\n",(*head)->data);
        *head=tail;
        free(x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("pop: %d\n",(*head)->data);
        free(*head);
        *head=NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    STACK *head = NULL;
    STACK *tail = NULL;
    push(&head,&tail,4);
    pop(&head,tail);
    push(&head,&tail,7);
    push(&head,&tail,9);
    show(tail);
    return 0;
}
```

I edited the code, now it works. Thank you everyone!!!

Comment: do not cast the result of malloc in C. Only in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most immediate problem is that you never initialize `head` and `tail` in `main()`:

```
STACK *head = NULL;
STACK *tail = NULL;
```

There are several other problems:

1. `pop()` leaks memory.
2. `show()` won't work if the list is empty (i.e. `tail` is `NULL`).
3. When the list is not empty, `show()` fails to print one of its elements.

Comment: i will have to look at the code more now but I think it does get initialized inside push. Since it accepts a double stack pointer and mallocs it in there

Comment: @Lefteris: Trust me, it doesn't.

Comment: yes you are right since he does not initialize both poitners to 0 at first. If he does then they should get initialized inside push.

Answer (score 2):

Right out of the gate, `head` and `tail` are uninitialized. That's going to be a no-go from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to

1) Initialize the two poitners inside main to 0 so they can be allocated by the push function

2) Removed the casting from malloc since this is C and it is not required.

3) You should also note the deficiencies the code has as pointed out by aix. (I did not fix them in the example below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack{
    int data;
    struct stack *next;
}STACK;

void push(STACK **head,STACK **tail,int n)
{
    STACK *x;
    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        (*head)=malloc(sizeof(STACK));
        (*head)->data=n;
        (*head)->next=NULL;
        *tail=*head;
    }
    else
    {
        x=malloc(sizeof(STACK));
        x->data=n;
        x->next=NULL;
        (*head)->next=x;
        (*head)=(*head)->next;
    }
}

void show(STACK *tail)
{
    while(tail->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",tail->data);
        tail=tail->next;
    }
}

void pop(STACK **head,STACK *tail)
{
    while(tail->next->next!=NULL)
        tail=tail->next;
    printf("pop: %d\n",(*head)->data);
    *head=tail;
}

int main()
{
    STACK *head = 0;
    STACK* tail = 0;
    push(&head,&tail,4);
    push(&head,&tail,7);
    push(&head,&tail,2);
    pop(&head,tail);
    show(tail);
    return 0;
}
```